# url rewriting with .htaccess php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

I want to make the username as part of the url, the url should go like this

`domanin.com/username/profile.html`

`domanin.com/username/events.html`

`domanin.com/username/messages.html`

Can you guide me how to do this?

If i registered with the site as ali then ali should be part of my url like

`domain.com/ali/profile.html`

`domain.com/ali/events.html`

Comment: What you want your rewritten url be look like and what would be actual url?Elaborate with example

Comment: @VarinderSingh the username will be replaced with the username of the user who select it at the time of registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I am doing this on my site where users can register, it's in php but can be modified to get what you want.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Full path
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite all php files    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Rewrite the user profile pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?user=$1
```

The first RewriteBase is the root directory of your site. The second Rewrite set under "# Rewrite all php files" will remove all .php file extensions from the files.

The third Rewrite set is what you are interested in. Profile.php is the users profile while ?user=$1 is the registered username. When the URL www.domain.com/user/userName/ is called it will actually get the data from the page profile.php?user=userName.

You will have to modify this a little bit to work how you want it, seeing as how mine is in php, but there are tutorials all over google on how to do this.

Comment: This site has a decent guide to url rewriting with .htaccess. http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/ if it doesn't have what you want, just google .htaccess mod_rewrite and you'll get TONS of results.